# WysiBB text editor uses [tag] instead of <tag>

Tags: html, tags, wysiwyg

I'm developing my own CMS (for my clientes) and I want to use WysiBB (http://www.wysibb.com/) for text areas. But the thing is that WysiBB saves html tags with [ ] instead of < > (ex. [h1]Text[/h1]) and then, the website doesn't recognise the [ ] tags. What should I do?

Comment: Your back end should be parsing that and outputting HTML.

Comment: Do I need any kind of script for doing it?

Comment: Normally BBcode is used in discussion forums, and the forum software does it. Sounds like you should be using an HTML WYSIWYG editor instead.

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm using WysiBB

Comment: WysiBB is a BBcode editor, not an HTML editor. "...WysiBB returns clean and correct bbcode."

Comment: So I should convert bbcode to HTML. Is that wright?

Answer (score 1):

I need to thank @isherwood for the help he gave me! Didn't realise that WysiBB was a BBcode editor cause I never heard about BBcode. What I did? I've implemented a function to convert BBCode to HTML.

```
//======================== START OF FUNCTION ==========================//
// FUNCTION: bbcode_to_html                                            //
//=====================================================================//
function bbcode_to_html($bbtext){
  $bbtags = array(
    '[heading1]' => '<h1>','[/heading1]' => '</h1>',
    '[heading2]' => '<h2>','[/heading2]' => '</h2>',
    '[heading3]' => '<h3>','[/heading3]' => '</h3>',
    '[h1]' => '<h1>','[/h1]' => '</h1>',
    '[h2]' => '<h2>','[/h2]' => '</h2>',
    '[h3]' => '<h3>','[/h3]' => '</h3>',

    '[paragraph]' => '<p>','[/paragraph]' => '</p>',
    '[para]' => '<p>','[/para]' => '</p>',
    '[p]' => '<p>','[/p]' => '</p>',
    '[left]' => '<p style="text-align:left;">','[/left]' => '</p>',
    '[right]' => '<p style="text-align:right;">','[/right]' => '</p>',
    '[center]' => '<p style="text-align:center;">','[/center]' => '</p>',
    '[justify]' => '<p style="text-align:justify;">','[/justify]' => '</p>',

    '[bold]' => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">','[/bold]' => '</span>',
    '[italic]' => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">','[/italic]' => '</span>',
    '[underline]' => '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">','[/underline]' => '</span>',
    '[b]' => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">','[/b]' => '</span>',
    '[i]' => '<span style="font-weight:bold;">','[/i]' => '</span>',
    '[u]' => '<span style="text-decoration:underline;">','[/u]' => '</span>',
    '[break]' => '<br>',
    '[br]' => '<br>',
    '[newline]' => '<br>',
    '[nl]' => '<br>',

    '[unordered_list]' => '<ul>','[/unordered_list]' => '</ul>',
    '[list]' => '<ul>','[/list]' => '</ul>',
    '[ul]' => '<ul>','[/ul]' => '</ul>',

    '[ordered_list]' => '<ol>','[/ordered_list]' => '</ol>',
    '[ol]' => '<ol>','[/ol]' => '</ol>',
    '[list_item]' => '<li>','[/list_item]' => '</li>',
    '[li]' => '<li>','[/li]' => '</li>',

    '[*]' => '<li>','[/*]' => '</li>',
    '[code]' => '<code>','[/code]' => '</code>',
    '[preformatted]' => '<pre>','[/preformatted]' => '</pre>',
    '[pre]' => '<pre>','[/pre]' => '</pre>',         
  );

  $bbtext = str_ireplace(array_keys($bbtags), array_values($bbtags), $bbtext);

  $bbextended = array(
    "/\[url](.*?)\[\/url]/i" => "<a href=\"http://$1\" title=\"$1\">$1</a>",
    "/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i" => "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"$1\">$2</a>",
    "/\[email=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/email\]/i" => "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$2</a>",
    "/\[mail=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/mail\]/i" => "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$2</a>",
    "/\[img\]([^[]*)\[\/img\]/i" => "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\" \" />",
    "/\[image\]([^[]*)\[\/image\]/i" => "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\" \" />",
    "/\[image_left\]([^[]*)\[\/image_left\]/i" => "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\" \" class=\"img_left\" />",
    "/\[image_right\]([^[]*)\[\/image_right\]/i" => "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\" \" class=\"img_right\" />",
  );

  foreach($bbextended as $match=>$replacement){
    $bbtext = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $bbtext);
  }
  return $bbtext;
}
//=====================================================================//
//  FUNCTION: bbcode_to_html                                           //
//========================= END OF FUNCTION ===========================//
```

And used it as the exemple above:

```
$bbtext = '[b]Text[/b]';

$html = bbcode_to_html($bbtext);

echo $html;
```

Comment: Do you also fax photos to yourself so you can mail them? Why not use the right tool for the job? http://www.tinymce.com ~ http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg ~ http://www.aloha-editor.org/

Comment: That might be better. I think I'll try bootstrap wysiwyg. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

API has two methods to work with the HTML code.

Get HTML content

```
$("#editor").htmlcode();
```

Set HTML content

```
$("#editor").htmlcode(htmlcode);
```

http://www.wysibb.com/docs/p9.html

I hope this helps you and others looking for answer